# I am not getting anything other than email from omniauth-google-oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am using devise plus ominauth in an application using the `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem but my auth hash is only returning with email even though this is my scope:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, GOOGLE_ID, GOOGLE_SECRET,
{
  :scope => "userinfo.email, userinfo.profile, plus.me",
  :prompt => "select_account consent",
  :image_aspect_ratio => "square",
  :image_size => 50
}
```

This is in my `config\initializers\devise.rb` file.

I can log in in with Google it shows these as the permissions my app needs but all I get in the callback is email.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This One this should Work For you...........

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_KEY"], ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET"],
    {
      :name => "google",
      :scope => "userinfo.email, userinfo.profile, plus.me, http://gdata.youtube.com",
      :prompt => "select_account",
      :image_aspect_ratio => "square",
      :image_size => 50
    }
end
```

For devise, you should also make sure you have an OmniAuth callback controller setup

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
      # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
      @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

      if @user.persisted?
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      else
        session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
  end
end
```

and bind to or create the user

```
def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.info
    user = User.where(:email => data["email"]).first

    unless user
        user = User.create(name: data["name"],
             email: data["email"],
             password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
            )
    end
    user
end
```

Comment: I am using ':omniauthable' with devise and I don't need any youtube control.

Comment: @thealbinosmurf are you building an app?

Comment: @Mehta not a mobile app

Comment: @thealbinosmurf i have edited my answer now make sure you have done this for devise or not

Comment: @thealbinosmurf
this link is surely helpful for you

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#google-oauth2-example

Comment: Im also using pry and in the `find_for_google_oauth2` I have a binding.pry so that I can see the data and I don't have anything other that the basics and email

Comment: I figured out that for some reason my server was out of sync with my code that you for the help